# Azure Static Web Apps -- config via CLI

Tags: azure-static-web-app

I have instances of Azure Static Web Apps that use the staticwebapp config json file.

Is there a method of updating just this (maybe via the AZ CLI?) or can this only be done on a deployment.

I know it is not a 'good way' to manage it but i have a short term and unusual set of circumstances.

Comment: What is the framework of your App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update/modify configuration file changes of your static web app, you need to make sure that `Enable configuration file changes` is enabled under `configuration` blade.

*Note:* Enabling configuration changes will only work if the static web app hosting plan is `standard`.

[image]

Once it is enabled, all the app settings have been moved to the `Environment variables` as shown above.

Now use [`az staticwebapp appsettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-staticwebapp-appsettings-set) CLI command to add or change the configuration settings as shown below.

```bash
az staticwebapp appsettings set --name newapj --resource-group xxx --setting-names "message=hi"
```

[image]

[image]

Also refer [doc1](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/docs/cli/swa-config/) with `Swa CLI` & [doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration) for configuration file changes.

Comment: Thats wonderful thanks. I need to update header values like the CSP and for a number of reasons I have to do it outside releases